# play math with sql commands

Tags: c#, sql

i'm working on restaurants programming with c#
working on the daily quantity of the material
i do count of the total that they make on the day then count how many they used and how many remaining on that day
my code is

```
 public void ExecuteQuery(string query)
        {
            foreach (Control txt in this.Controls)
            {
                if (txt.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
                        txt.Text = "0";
            }

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            com.Parameters.Add("@shish_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shish_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@bani_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bani_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@zingr_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = zingr_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@tabona_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tabona_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@fahita_chkn_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fahita_chkn_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@borger_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = borger_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabab_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabab_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shgef_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shgef_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@faheta_met_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = faheta_met_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabda_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabda_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_met_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_met_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_chkn_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_chkn_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_mash_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_mash_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_red_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_red_add.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@patata_add", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patata_add.Text;

            com.Parameters.Add("@shish_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shish_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@bani_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bani_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@zingr_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = zingr_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@tabona_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tabona_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@fahita_chkn_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fahita_chkn_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@borger_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = borger_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabab_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabab_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shgef_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shgef_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@faheta_met_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = faheta_met_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabda_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabda_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_met_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_met_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_chkn_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_chkn_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_mash_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_mash_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_red_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_red_take.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@patata_take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patata_take.Text;

            com.Parameters.Add("@shish_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shish_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@bani_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bani_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@zingr_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = zingr_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@tabona_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tabona_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@fahita_chkn_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fahita_chkn_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@borger_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = borger_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabab_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabab_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shgef_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shgef_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@faheta_met_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = faheta_met_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@kabda_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kabda_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_met_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_met_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@shawo_chkn_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shawo_chkn_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_mash_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_mash_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@chkn_red_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkn_red_rom.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@patata_rom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patata_rom.Text;

            com.Parameters.Add("@dates", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dates.Value.Date;


            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            foreach (Control txt in this.Controls)
            {
                if (txt.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    if (txt.Text == "0")
                        txt.Text = "";
            }
            MessageBox.Show("تمت عملية الاضافة بنجاح", "ملاحظة", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        }
        public void doqury(string strn)
        {
            string sqlQuery = strn;
             ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            // check for first time entry 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from megana_cooking ", connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                //mean there values on database
                //now need to check is this a new day or not
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from megana_cooking where dates = @dates", connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader1.HasRows)
                {
                    //no this is the take valus statment
                reader.Close();
                doqury("UPDATE megana_cooking SET  shish_rom =shish_add - @shish_take ,bani_rom =bani_add - @bani_take ,zingr_rom =zingr_add - @zingr_take ,tabona_rom =tabona_add - @tabona_take ,fahita_chkn_rom =fahita_chkn_add - @fahita_chkn_take ,borger_rom =borger_add - @borger_take ,kabab_rom =kabab_add - @kabab_take ,shgef_rom =shgef_add - @shgef_take ,faheta_met_rom =faheta_met_add - @faheta_met_take ,kabda_rom =kabda_add - @kabda_take ,shawo_met_rom =shawo_met_add - @shawo_met_take ,shawo_chkn_rom =shawo_chkn_add - @shawo_chkn_take ,chkn_mash_rom =chkn_mash_add - @chkn_mash_take ,chkn_red_rom =chkn_red_add - @chkn_red_take ,patata_rom =patata_add - @patata_take ,patata_take =@patata_take,chkn_red_take =@chkn_red_take,chkn_mash_take =@chkn_mash_take,shawo_chkn_take =@shawo_chkn_take,shawo_met_take =@shawo_met_take,kabda_take =@kabda_take,faheta_met_take =@faheta_met_take,shgef_take =@shgef_take,kabab_take =@kabab_take,borger_take =@borger_take,fahita_chkn_take =@fahita_chkn_take,tabona_take =@tabona_take,zingr_take =@zingr_take,bani_take =@bani_take,shish_take =@shish_take ,dates =@dates  where dates = @dates ");

                }

                else
                {
                    // yes new day new values and add value to the remain values from last entry 
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("سيتم ادخال بيانات ليوم جديد " + Environment.NewLine + " سيقوم بأدخال البيانات دون احتساب عملية السحب", "تأكيد", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                     MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
                    doqury("INSERT INTO megana_cooking ( shish_add ,bani_add ,zingr_add ,tabona_add ,fahita_chkn_add ,borger_add ,kabab_add ,shgef_add ,faheta_met_add ,kabda_add ,shawo_met_add ,shawo_chkn_add ,chkn_mash_add ,chkn_red_add ,patata_add ,dates ) VALUES ( @shish_add ,@bani_add ,@zingr_add ,@tabona_add ,@fahita_chkn_add ,@borger_add ,@kabab_add ,@shgef_add ,@faheta_met_add ,@kabda_add ,@shawo_met_add ,@shawo_chkn_add ,@chkn_mash_add ,@chkn_red_add ,@patata_add ,@dates )");
                    //insert new quentity done now need to update the remain value 
                    //new quentity + last remain 

here need to find the last date that it have value then update and add the new quantity to it 


                }


            }
            else
            {
                //this is first entry
                reader.Close();

                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("سيتم ادخال البيانات الى المنظومة لاول مره " + Environment.NewLine + " سيقوم بأدخال البيانات دون احتساب عملية السحب", "تأكيد", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                      MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);

                doqury("INSERT INTO megana_cooking ( shish_add ,bani_add ,zingr_add ,tabona_add ,fahita_chkn_add ,borger_add ,kabab_add ,shgef_add ,faheta_met_add ,kabda_add ,shawo_met_add ,shawo_chkn_add ,chkn_mash_add ,chkn_red_add ,patata_add ,shish_rom ,bani_rom ,zingr_rom ,tabona_rom ,fahita_chkn_rom ,borger_rom ,kabab_rom ,shgef_rom ,faheta_met_rom ,kabda_rom ,shawo_met_rom ,shawo_chkn_rom ,chkn_mash_rom ,chkn_red_rom ,patata_rom ,dates ) VALUES ( @shish_add ,@bani_add ,@zingr_add ,@tabona_add ,@fahita_chkn_add ,@borger_add ,@kabab_add ,@shgef_add ,@faheta_met_add ,@kabda_add ,@shawo_met_add ,@shawo_chkn_add ,@chkn_mash_add ,@chkn_red_add ,@patata_add ,@shish_add ,@bani_add ,@zingr_add ,@tabona_add ,@fahita_chkn_add ,@borger_add ,@kabab_add ,@shgef_add ,@faheta_met_add ,@kabda_add ,@shawo_met_add ,@shawo_chkn_add ,@chkn_mash_add ,@chkn_red_add ,@patata_add ,@dates )");


            }
            connection.Close();


        }
```

the question is
i need to find the last date that it have value then update and add the new quantity to it i did mention it in my code
i know i can because when i tried this code on new query on sql management studio it work

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
    megana_cooking
ORDER BY 
    dates
    update megana_cooking set shish_rom = shish_rom + '5'
```

can i make the sql command shorter than this by using sql programmability or server side because i have more than 15 type of the material food
i have weak knowledge about sql
thank you in advance

Comment: As an overall observation I would suggest not having a separate column for each type of food. This makes it hard whenever you want to change the menu, you don't want to be changing your table structure just for that. Also it makes it hard to do totals etc if you needed to get statistics. Instead I would suggest to have a separate table where each type is one one row (with a column for the name of the food and then a column for the quantity, and probably another for the date that entry relates to, with a foreign key back to the main cooking table)

Comment: you can think this is not a menu actually this is thing close to be a store and need to mange how many they add and take from it thank for your replay

Comment: Even so, if they change their stock items from time to time it would be more sensible if it could be done simply by adding a row into a table instead of having to create a new column and then change all the SQL queries

Comment: i asked the costumer if they ganna change there material and they says all that they have and they never ganna change it  !

Comment: I would take the view that doing something in the way that can easily be modified is the correct way to do things - regardless of what your customer said today - you can guarantee at some point in the future they will change their mind. ADyson's advice in the first comment should seriously be considered.

Comment: PaulF is correct. And as well as that flexibility, it will make other kinds of queries against your data easier to write.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, I'm not sure I totally understand. You said _"i need to find the last date that it have value"_ ...is the last date not always today? Or at least the most recent working day? Is there a problem deciding which date was the most recent?

Comment: @ ADyson no it not daily work that why i cant use the day before and add to them the new quantity to the remain of the quantity that left from last day before

Comment: ok but surely whatever is the latest row in the database will have the relevant information in it. So all you need to do is get the most recent date added to the table. Even if that product wasn't made on that day, you would simply have copied the quantity from the previous day, I expect?

Comment: yes ! but how i can copy the quantity from the previous day ?